# type specifier is missng and int is assumed c++

Tags: c++

There is some simple C++ console app where I've got `Utility.h` which looks like this

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

class Utility
{

public:
    Utility();
    ~Utility();

    static Plane* getPlanes(const char* fileName);
    static arma::vec getDirectionVector(int phi, int theta);
};
```

and I've got `Utility.cpp` which looks like

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Utility.h"


    Utility::Utility()
    {
    } 

    Plane* Utility::getPlanes(const char* fileName)
    {
        const char *p_chInputFileName = fileName;
        ifstream *p_inFileStream;
        Plane *p_confiningPlanes;
        ..........................................
        .........................................
        return p_confiningPlanes;
    }

    arma::vec getDirectionVector(int phi, int theta)
    {
        arma::vec direcitonVector(3);
        direcitonVector.at(0) = cos(theta) * cos(phi);
        direcitonVector.at(1) = cos(theta) * sin(phi);
        direcitonVector.at(3) = sin(theta);

        return direcitonVector;
    }


Utility::~Utility()
{
}
```

I also have some other files in my project which I don't think are important.
My compiler keeps telling me that `; is missing before *` and that `type specifier is missng and int is assumed` in line

```
static Plane* getPlanes(const char* fileName);
```

I have no clue about what is happening and this problem came up after I deleted from and added again to my project some classes and probably something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m guessing it doesn’t realize that `Plane` is a class, and thinks instead you’re trying to declare a static member named `Plane` (and warns you that it’s assuming it’s of type `int` since you didn’t give it a type).

Add `struct Plane;` before `class Utility {` in your `Utility.h` to forward-declare `Plane`, which should make it understand that `Plane` is a type, not the name of a member you’re trying to declare, and hence solve your problem.

(I should also note that many people frown on `using namespace std;` at the top level in header files.)

Comment: ty, declarin Plane class in header actually helped but what also helped is that I swapped two #include's in "stdafx.h" precompiled header which were #include "Plane.h" and #include "Utility.h". Wouldn't ever think that it may matter, c++ looks strange when you come here from c#.

Comment: @Ilia Include order should not and usually does not matter in C++. The non-standard and not portable "stdafx.h" is the only common exception I know of. Honestly, I feel like people should stop using those unnecessary extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In `utility.h` you have

```
static Plane* getPlanes(const char* fileName);
```

But there is nothing in the header file to tell the compiler what a `Plane` is.  You either need to include the file that has the `Plane` type in it or forward declare it in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler about `Plane`.

The most basic way of doing this is to include the header that defines `Plane` in `Utility.h`.

A more advanced way of doing this is to forward declare the class or struct by adding `class Plane;` or `struct Plane;`, as appropriate, to `Utility.h` before `class Utility`, and then include the header that defines `Plane` in `Utility.cpp`. You can do this because in the header you only have a pointer to `Plane`, and therefore the compiler only needs to know of it's existence. While to use it you need to include the definition of the class/struct.